Order of Picard groups of non-hyperelliptic algebraic curves
Let $q$ be prime. When $E/\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ is an elliptic curve, it is well-known that the group of $\mathbb{F}_q$-points of $E$ is isomorphic to the Picard group of degree $0$ divisors on $E$ (well the Picard group over $\mathbb{F}_q$, but we will suppress this):
$$E(\mathbb{F}_q)\simeq \operatorname{Pic}^0(E)$$
and thus the Hasse-Weil bound gives us that the order of $\operatorname{Pic}^0(E)$ satisfies
$$q+1-2\sqrt{q}\leq \#  \operatorname{Pic}^0(E) \leq q+1+2\sqrt{q} $$
Now consider a hyperelliptic curve $H/\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ of genus $g$. From here, we see that $$(\sqrt{q}-1)^{2g} \leq \#  \operatorname{Pic}^0(H) \leq (\sqrt{q}+1)^{2g}$$ but there is no proof provided.
Question 1: How does one prove this? Is it related to the Hasse-Weil bound for general algebraic curves?
Hasse-Weil Bound For a general genus $g$ algebraic curve (smooth, irreducible, etc), we have the Hasse-Weil bound $$|\#H(\mathbb{F}_q)-q-1|\leq 2g\sqrt{q}$$
Since this is defined in general, it seems that if there is an affirmative answer to question $1$, then one should be able to show a similar bound for the orders of Picard groups of arbitrary (eg non-hyperelliptic) algebraic curves:
Question 2 Does the same bound hold for $\operatorname{Pic}^0(C_g)$ for an arbitrary genus $g$ curve $C_g$? If not, what bounds are known?

That doesn't look right to me; I think the exponent should be $2g$ (it should reduce to the Hasse-Weil bound when $g = 1$). I'm not familiar with the details but I think this is a corollary of the Weil conjectures applied to the Jacobian variety, which should have a relatively elementary proof in this case. The Hasse-Weil bound is a corollary of the Weil conjectures applied to the curve itself which is different.

Meant to write $2g$, thanks! It is fixed now.
